# React Router adding up instead of changing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm making a dropdown in a navbar using semantic-ui-react as you can see[image]

inside drowpdown there are 3 dropdown items (suppose "Apples", "Mangoes" and "Bananas"). On clicking any one, the content below navbar changes , suppose if I clicked apples then Apples description will be  shown below navbar. But the problem is that when I'm in "Apples" route(`docs/Apple`) and then I'm clicking Mangoes (from dropdown inside "Apples" route) then route is adding up like `/docs/docs/Mangoes` instead of `docs/Mangoes`.

What should I do?
Sorry if the question is common, I'm new to React.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Without see your code I can guess that your are calling `push` without first `/`, isn't it?
`push('docs/xxxx')` ... To fix it add a slash `push('/docs/xxxx')`

Comment: Glad it helped you ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think ,you must used "exact"
Match from exactly; equivalent to Route.exact.

exact When true, the active class/style will only be applied if the location is matched exactly.